# ¿Cómo relacionar una tabla con 2 claves foraneas, que a su vez tienen una relación de muchos a muchos entre ellas?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Tengo tres tablas y no me queda claro cual debería ser la forma correcta de relacionarlas.

Primero tengo la tabla `caballos`, donde cada caballo tiene 1 capa y 1 raza (claves foraneas de las respectivas tablas), esto serían relaciones de 1 a muchos (un caballo siempre tiene 1 capa y 1 raza, pero una misma capa o raza puede pertencer a muchos caballos).

```
CREATE TABLE caballos ( 
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
id_raza INT NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT FK_razas_caballos FOREIGN KEY (id_raza) REFERENCES razas(id_raza),
id_capa INT NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT FK_capas_caballos FOREIGN KEY (id_capa) REFERENCES capas(id_capa)
);
```

Después tengo las tablas de `capas` y `razas`:

```
CREATE TABLE capas ( 
id_capa INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
capa VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE razas ( 
id_raza INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
raza VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL
);
```

Las tablas `capas` y `razas` también están relacionadas entre ellas, tienen una relación muchos a muchos porque una raza puede tener muchas capas y una capa puede ser de varias razas. Por lo tanto también creo la tabla `capas_razas` de relación:

```
CREATE TABLE capas_razas ( 
id_capa INT,
id_raza INT,
CONSTRAINT FK_capas_razas1 FOREIGN KEY (id_capa) REFERENCES capas(id_capa),
CONSTRAINT FK_capas_razas2 FOREIGN KEY (id_raza) REFERENCES razas(id_raza),
CONSTRAINT capas_razas_unique UNIQUE (id_capa, id_raza)
);
```

En la creación de la tabla `caballos` anterior que puesto el `id_capa` y el `id_raza` como claves foraneas de las tablas `capas` y `razas`, porque un caballo tiene tanto una raza como una capa. Pero no sé si en vez de relacionarlo como lo he hecho, debería haber algún tipo de relación con la tabla de relación `capas_razas` que tampoco sé muy bien como montar.

¿Alguien me podría indicar si mi forma de relacionarlo es correcta, o cuál debería ser la mejor forma de hacerlo?

Muchas gracias :)

Comment: Algo no me cuadra en tu modelo, lo pienso desde el punto de vista de la realidad. No tiene ningún sentido que un caballo tenga una sola `raza` y una sola `capa`, y que a su vez una `raza` pueda relacionarse con varias `capa` y viceversa. ¿Puedes explicarnos qué es una `capa` realmente en tu modelo de datos, para tratar de entenderlo de una forma **realista**? No parece haber una jerarquía de relaciones, meter `capa` en `caballo` parece algo dislocado. ¿Por qué tiene que estar `capa` en `caballo`?

Comment: Todos los caballos tiene una raza, por ej. pura sangre. Pero dentro de la raza pura sangre hay muchos colores del pelaje (capas) ej. castaño, alazán, gris tordo, etc. Por lo que un caballo siempre tendrá una raza y una capa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si hay una relación entre capas y razas, entonces los caballos no se relación 1 a n con capas y 1 a n con razas, si no que se relacionan 1 a n con la intersección de capas y razas.

Pongámoslo de otra forma.

Tomamos un caballo.. por lo que contas, se relaciona con capa1 y con raza1. Por lo tanto, según tu modelo, debería si o si existir una entrada en la tabla capas_razas que fuera capa1/raza1. Esa tabla, debería tener un id único (llamemoslo id1), con lo cual, tu caballo debería si o si, relacionarse con id1, no con cada capa y raza por separado, si no, para que tendrías esa tabla?

Por lo tanto, la tabla caballos se relaciona con capas_razas y su clave es el id único de esa tabla, no los dos id (para que tener dos id como clave?, aunque se puede, solo complejizan el modelo).

Ejemplo:

Tabla razas

| id | raza |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | raza1 |
| 2 | raza2 |

Tabla capas

| id | capas |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | capas1 |
| 2 | capas2 |

en tu tabla caballos tendrias lo siguiente:

| id | id_raza | id_capa |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |

Entonces, segun lo que contabas, deberia existir en la tabla capas_razas lo siguiente:

| id_raza | id_capas | id_unico(deberias crearlo) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 |

Y entonces, para que crear los dos id en tu tabla caballo? mejor relacionarlo directo a la tabla capas_razas de la siguiente forma

tu tabla caballos

| id | id_capas_razas |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |

Comment: Me parece un rompecabezas el modelo de OP. Sería interesante que nos explique qué es `capa` (desde el punto de vista de la realidad) y por qué tiene que haber una referencia a `capa` en `caballo`.

Comment: No... si entendiste eso, lo explique mal @A.Cedano... voy a ver si puedo hacer un der para explicarlo, lo que pasa es que desde donde estoy no puedo usar imagenes... a ver si se lo puedo explicar mejor...

Comment: @A.Cedano ni idea si la relacion capas razas es algo logico, solo explique la relacion entre tablas... ahi se entiende mejor?

Comment: La capa es el color del pelaje de un caballo, el cual es un atributo del caballo pero también es cierto que depende de la raza. Un caballo siempre tiene una raza y una capa, pero no todas las razas tienen todas las capas existentes. Y creo que tu planteamiento de las tablas tiene sentido, porque al final la raza y la capa son dos atributos relacionados no independientes

Comment: Ahora sí se entiende mejor tu planteamiento gbianchi, más aún sabiendo lo que es la `capa`, luego de que @itaca9 lo haya explicado. El error, a mi juicio, fue meter dos referencias, una a `raza` y otra a `capa` en `caballo`, eso era lo que no encajaba en mi cabeza, porque realmente basta con una referencia, que debería tomarse de la tabla (última) que propones en tu respuesta.